# Upload binary file with retrofit 2 in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to upload a binary file to the server in Android. I test Api method by postman:

[image]

And it's OK, as you see there is another option which you can upload files as form data(key, value):

[image]

Every tutorials (like [this one](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server))describe how to upload files as `multipart/form-data`:

```
 // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

I search a lot but couldn't find any way to upload file as binary with retrofit2.

There is just one Issue in **retrofit** repository which ask **[How can I POST a image binary in retrofit 2.0 beta?](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1217)**. I use its solution :

API Service:

```
@POST("trip/{tripId}/media/photos")
Call<MediaPost> postEventPhoto(
    @Path("eventId") int tripId,
    @Header("Authorization") String accessToken,
    @Query("direction") String direction,
    @Body RequestBody photo);
```

Caller:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(media.getPath()));
byte[] buf;
buf = new byte[in.available()];
while (in.read(buf) != -1);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody
    .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buf);
Call<MediaPost> mediaPostCall = tripApiService.postTripPhoto(
    tripId,
    ((GlobalInfo) getApplicationContext()).getApiAccessToken(),
    direction,
    requestBody);
```

But I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.
```

What's wrong with my code? what should I do?

Comment: `it's OK, as you see there is another option which you can upload files as form data(key, value):`. Wrong. Key=value is when x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: There is no need to manually read the bytes. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755954/1369016

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After hours of searching I found that there was an `@Multipart` annotation remains in API interface of my code from last example! which prevent to send binary data to the server and the solution in retrofit repository was OK!

Comment: Serious it helpful, did same thing. Appreciated Feeling great after long struggle :D

Comment: You forgot to add it or you removed it?

Comment: @Hamed can you post your method definition

Comment: You answer is not understandable for newbie.

Comment: God! This happened to me too.. wasted a lot of time.

Answer (score 13):

Just adding another solution, as I had to dig a bit to understand what happened in the question in the first place.

My solution is to get the binary file as a `byte[]` directly and then put it inside the `RequestBody`. So in the end, the code would look like this:

```
interface RetrofitService {
    @POST("api/v1/upload_file")
    Call<Void> uploadBinaryFile(@Body RequestBody body);
}
```

And to call it:

```
public void uploadBinaryFile(File fileToUpload) {
    retrofitService
        .uploadBinaryFile(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet"), 
            Files.readAllBytes(fileToUpload));
}
```

This is basically the same as OP's original question, but just for the sake of clarity I'll leave this answer as well for the next reader.

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin you can do this:

```
val file: File = retrieveMyJavaFile()
val requestBody: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("application/octet-stream".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val response: MyResponse = myAPI.uploadPhoto(requestBody).body()!!
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, I wanted to upload binary file(image). The API was of Wordpress

I followed the solution code which is given at the end of [this issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1217)

Here is my little modified code

```
@POST("wp-json/wp/v2/media/")
Call<ImagePostResult> postEventPhoto(
        @Header("Authorization") String accessToken,
        @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
        @Header("Content-Disposition") String contentDisposition,
        @Body RequestBody photo);
```

Here is the request

```
        // For BasicAuth
        String authHeader = getAuthHeader();

        String contentType = "application/binary";
        String contentDisposition = "attachment; filename =  " + fileName;

        RequestBody requestBodyee = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

            byte[] buf;
            buf = new byte[in.available()];
            while (in.read(buf) != -1) ;
            requestBodyee = RequestBody
                    .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Call<ImagePostResult> imagePostResultCall = apiInterface.postEventPhoto(
                authHeader,
                contentType,
                contentDisposition,
                requestBodyee);
        imagePostResultCall.enqueue(new Callback<ImagePostResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ImagePostResult> call, Response<ImagePostResult> response) {
                // Response Success
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  // yaay
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ImagePostResult> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also send the image in

```
//Api Interface

@Part MultipartBody.Part body


//Call in activity
     file = FileUtils.getFile(this, uri);
                            reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                            body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", "Img_" + "_" + rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg", reqFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

just MediaType == Null 
my code:

```
  private fun put(uploadUrl : String , localPath : String) {
        val file = File(localPath)
        val byteArray = file2Byte(localPath)!!
        val responseBody = RequestBody.create(null , byteArray)
        val call = HttpFactory.providerUp.up(uploadUrl , responseBody)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onFailure(call : retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody>? , t : Throwable?) {
                LogUtil.toast("Failure")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call : retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody>? , response : retrofit.Response<ResponseBody>?) {
                if (response!!.code() == 200) {
                    LogUtil.toast("YES")
                } else {
                    LogUtil.toast("NO")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

```
@PUT
    fun up2(@Url url : String ,@Body requestBody : RequestBody ) : Call<ResponseBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am upload image to server same like this but in **volley** ,Here is my code
Hope this is helpfull for someone

```
public void uploadImageToServer(byte[] value) {
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,uploadImageURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("s3 response", response);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Image Uploaded to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("error response", error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Image Not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headerMap.put("header1", "header value");
                headerMap.put("header2", "header value");
                headerMap.put("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
                Log.e("header", headerMap.toString());
                return headerMap;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return value;
            }

        };
        {
            int socketTimeout = 30000;
            RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.getCache().clear();
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If any android developer want to upload file over the server using binary data with the help of volley.

```
public void uploadImageToServer (byte[] imageByte) {
            final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,uploadImageURL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.e("s3 response", response);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Uploaded to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("error response", error.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
    
    
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headerMap.put("header1", "header value");
                    headerMap.put("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
                    return headerMap;
                }
    
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
               //Binary value data
                    return value;
                }
    
            };
            {
                int socketTimeout = 30000;
                RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                requestQueue.getCache().clear();
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        }



 
//You can convert any file to byte array
 public static byte[] convertFileToBytes(File file)
    {
     int size = (int) userImageFile.length();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(userImageFile));
            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            buf.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: Even though your answer may be working, the OP is asking how to upload a file using **Retrofit**, not **Volley**.